# The PowerShell window is always cleaned after a script has been executed

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, terminal, console

I run a PowerShell script form the PowerShell and whatever method I choose it always cleans my current PowerShell window which is pretty annoying. That doesn't happen with Linux PowerShell.

This is how I run a PowerShell script:

```
powershell.exe -File "/path/to/file.ps1
```

or

```
powershell -c ". /path/to/file.ps1"
```

No matter how I call the script, the current PowerShell window is cleaned and the only thing I can see is the output of the script that I called. All previously displayed text is deleted.

Maybe there are options to prevent this behavior?

See also my screenshots as a visual representation of the problem:

- My PowerShell window before I ran the command - [image: PS window before]
- My PowerShell window after I ran a command - [image: PS window after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-NoProfile` solves the problem:

```
powershell -NoProfile  -c 'Write-Host OK'
```